# Passing a value from database to vue component and assigning it to a variable

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to pass a value from my database and then assign that value to a variable in my `Vue Component`. This successfully gets the data from the database however i get error when assigning that value to a variable in the component:

- "TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined"

Vue Component:

```
import TransactionsService from '@/services/TransactionsService'
export default {
    components: {
    },
    data(){
        return {
            transactions: null,
            product: null,
            amount: null
        }
    },
    async mounted() {
        try{
        this.transactions = (await TransactionsService.index()).data.transactions

        for( transaction in transactions){
            this.amount = transaction.amount
        }
        console.log(amount)

        this.userId = this.$store.state.user.priviledge
        } catch(error){
            this.error = error.response.data.message
        }      
    }
}
```

I want to assign the value at `transaction.amount` to the variable `amount`

Comment: what is the return data structure of `TransactionsService.index()`

Comment: @AndrewNolan an array. i have added it to the question

Comment: doesn't seem to be `data` in the path down to `transactions`

Comment: thats odd becuase im using `transactions` in my html part and im using a `v-for` to access and display those values. so im unsure as to why im getting this error for `transactions` now when im trying to assign it to a variable

Comment: i changed it to `console.log(error)` and its now saying `transaction` is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that [`for ... in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop, `transaction` is the item's array index, not the item itself.  Here is a more common loop:

```js
// forEach
transactions.forEach(transaction => {
   this.amount = transaction.amount 
})
```

This loop will work but still doesn't make sense because you will only keep setting `this.amount` to the next `transaction` amount and overwriting the last one.  If you intended to add them up you could use:

```js
this.amount += transaction.amount
```

<sub>(Note:  It's a good practice to use any other loop type with arrays because index order isn't guaranteed with `for ... in`.  Alternatives are `forEach`, `for`, or [`for ... of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of))</sub>